# window.scrollTo weirdness inside Android webview

Tags: javascript, android

I'm having a weird issue when I use `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)` to scroll to the bottom of a page (loaded inside an Android webview). There's a huge gap of whitespace at the bottom of the page (it disappears when the page is tapped). Does anyone have any advice? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what the view looks like? If this was a webpage I'd assume it was a `padding-bottom` CSS rule.